# aws api gateway enable api_key for authentication

Tags: api, authentication, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have added api_key to my rest api in aws api gateway for authenticating a GET request method.

My request is:

`curl -X GET -H "x-amz-key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXQklq4C7vbEGprA" "https://XXXXXXXXXXX.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/test/10/12/+"`

I keep getting the following error:

`{"message": "Forbidden"}`

I am doing everything as the AWS docs mention. Can anybody point me to the right direction here, how to add api_key in request?

The same request works fine if api_key authentication is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the attribute is `x-api-key` not `x-amz-key`

From the [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-api-keys.html)

> Callers must now add to each call a custom header named x-api-key,
>   along with the value of the API key. For example, if the API key value
>   is *bkayZOMvuy8aZOhIgxq94K9Oe7Y70Hw55*, the custom header would be as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> x-api-key: bkayZOMvuy8aZOhIgxq94K9Oe7Y70Hw55
> ```